# How to instal usb soundcard Drive on raspberry pi3 for the google assistant sdk?

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

I want to connect my mic and speaker to raspberry pi using an usb sound card for the google assistant SDK .BUT its not detecting the sound card

Comment: Does your system recognize the sound card?

Comment: yes it recognize the sound card.